# Cannot get IF $_GET[video] = edit, display a form

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement, get

I cannot seem to figure this out. I'm trying to get row[video] value from results, and if there is a entry in the DB for video and it's not null, display a link that says Edit Video Link with a href= of edit_media.php?video=edit (which is this page). If the user clicks this link, the page reloads with the URL including video=edit and that triggers the variable videoEdit to be TRUE which should display a form input box that displays the current value in the database.

However, It doesn't seem to be working, for some reason I'm seeing the form input box even before I click Edit Video link, (url does not have video=edit). and when I click "Modify Video Link" and the url does have the video=edit, I see a textbox with the words Video in it. I'm not sure why. I have the correct MYSQL Query before this code, but I didn't include it here. How can I get this working?

```
     // if the user clicked edit video link
if ($_GET['video'] = EDIT) {
$videoEdit = TRUE
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, mysql_assoc)) {
$video = $row['video'];
}

if ($videoEdit = TRUE) {
echo '<form action="edit_media.php" method="post">
<p>Video Link: <input type="text" name="serial" size="25" maxlength="100" value=';
       if (isset($video))
            echo $video;
            ' /></p><p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Video" /></p>               <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
        </form>';
}
```

And it goes on to say:

```
if ($video != "") {
echo '<iframe width="420" height="315" src=' . $video . ' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> | <a href=edit_media.php?video=EDIT>Modify Video Link</a>';
} else {
echo "Video Not Present | <a href=edit_media.php?video=EDIT>Add a Video</a>";
}
```

Can you help me in making this script work>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you're need a comparisons, not assignments:

```
if ($_GET['video'] ==  'EDIT') {
     $videoEdit = TRUE;
 }
```

and

```
if ($videoEdit == TRUE) {
```

Also the printing of your video needs to be cleaned up:

```
echo '<form action="edit_media.php" method="post">
      <p>Video Link: <input type="text" name="serial" size="25" maxlength="100" value=';
if (isset($video)){
        echo $video;
}
echo ' /></p><p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Video"/></p>'.
     '<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" /> </form>';
```

Comment: This works, but when the page goes into video=edit mode. The Form text box displays the character / instead of the actual link in the database field.

Comment: OK - when I run echo $video; directly before the if ($videoEdit) { statement it outputs on the page the URL of the video in the Database. But if I include that same line under the if ($videoEdit) {, I get nadda. nothing. zero. squat.

Answer (score 0):

In your two if statement you have miss a "=" your code correct:

```
if ($_GET['video'] == EDIT) {
$videoEdit = TRUE
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, mysql_assoc)) {
$video = $row['video'];
}

if ($videoEdit == TRUE) {
echo '<form action="edit_media.php" method="post">
<p>Video Link: <input type="text" name="serial" size="25" maxlength="100" value=';
       if (isset($video))
            echo $video;
            ' /></p><p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Video" /></p>               <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
        </form>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is using the wrong comparisson operator:

`if ($videoEdit = TRUE) {`

It should be

`if ($videoEdit == TRUE) {`

Answer (score 0):

Alot of syntax errors here.. I suggest doing some learning... Here's what I could see..

Also, while your researching... Look into PDO or Doctrine, mysql is deprecated.

```
if ($_GET['video'] == 'EDIT') { // <<--- invalid syntax
$videoEdit = TRUE; // <--- missing semicolon
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // <-- not sure
$video = $row['video'];
}

if ($videoEdit) { // <-- boolean comparison
echo '<form action="edit_media.php" method="post">
<p>Video Link: <input type="text" name="serial" size="25" maxlength="100" value=';
       if (isset($video))
            echo $video;
            ' /></p><p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Video" /></p>               <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
        </form>';
}
```

Here's a great resource: http://www.php.net/manual/en/

Answer (score 0):

Try this
        if ($_GET['video'] == "EDIT") 
        {
        $videoEdit = TRUE
        }

Answer (score 0):

This is assigning EDIT to the variable, not checking its value.

```
if ($_GET['video'] = EDIT)
```

Try getting into the habit of writing constants check in reverse order:

```
if (EDIT == $_GET['video'])
```

This way, if you ever drop a '=' again, the code won't compile at all and you'll be immediately warned.

For the same reason, be wary of `if ($a == $b)` comparisons.

Comment: It works now, but the URL to the video link in the DB will not output below the if ($videoEdit) { conditional, if I echo $video before that conditional it displays the link, but if I echo $video inside that conditional, I get nothing. Do you know why>?